# Is there any deep learning library that gives option to calculate mfcc as the layer of deep learning mode

Tags: deep-learning, mfcc

I want to calculate mfcc as a layer of deep learning model, as Kapre gives option to calculate Log spectrograms or mel spectrograms as a layer of deep learning model. can anybody suggest any deep learning library in Python for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **torchaudio.transforms.MFCC** from the torchaudio package, or **librosa.feature.mfcc** from the librosa package.

Comment: Please consider providing some supporting source code or sample implementation showing how it solves the problem.